# JSTL Taglib Showing Hidden Parameters

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts

we are having some issue with JSTL Taglib below since sometimes are showed in the browser even if input type is declared "hidden"

```
<c:forEach var="homeDesc" items="${homeDescBean.homeCategories}">
    <input type="hidden" id='${homeDesc.category}'value='${homeDesc.title}_${homeDesc.experience}_${homeDesc.description}' />
</c:forEach>
```

looking at the generated HTML we see:

```
<input type="hidden" id="O2" value="VALUE &nbsp;16 mq.">
<input type="hidden" id="S3" value="VALUE_VALUE_<br /><div xmlns=" http:="" www.w3.org="" 1999="" xhtml'="">
VALUE THAT SHOULD BE HIDDEN</div>
```

please notice that the the `<br /><div...` does not come from our code and is generated from some reason by JSTL.

Comment: Have you checked there's no odd characters in `homeDesc.title` or `homeDesc.experience` or `homeDesc.description` that may affect this? Also, why are you setting a (probably long) description as value in your hidden field? This makes me wonder about your current design.

Comment: Hi Luiggi, we have no visibility on the parameter we will recieve. do you have any suggestion to solve the issue without the usage of scriptlets?

Comment: Use `<c:out>` that handles this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a slew of quotes in that value, which is making it break from the quotes around value="".  You need to replace the quotes with the HTML entity. You would do the replacement in the controller, set this is the request attribute, and use JSTL.

In the controller:

```
String str = "VALUE_VALUE_<br /><div xmlns=\" http:=\"\" www.w3.org=\"\" 1999=\"\" xhtml'=\"\">\nVALUE THAT SHOULD BE HIDDEN</div>";
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
request.setAttribute("htmlsnippet", str);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/show.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In the JSP:

```
<c:out value="${htmlsnippet}" />
```

EDIT: But sending hardcoded HTML/XML to the server in a hidden input is a bad idea. You're going to have to validate it again on the server-side, so you might as well leave it in the back-end entirely. Putting it in a hidden input and sending it back to the server gives the user the chance to alter it.

Comment: Going back to the era of the dinosaurs to solve the problem? Seriously?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, Are you saying a string replace is the era of the dinosaurs? I mentioned that the scriptlet is only to confirm quickly that this works.

Comment: No, scriptlet is from the era of dinosaurs. It would be better using `<c:out value="${homeDesc.category}" />` and others instead.

Comment: @developerwjk Rendering HTML content in controller is also a dinosaurs approach.

Comment: So, what is a replacement in the controller?

Comment: @Roman C, I've updated it to get rid of the scriplet so everyone can be happy.

Comment: No, you didn't get what I said, putting HTML code that is hardcoded in the controller to the request attribute _is also a dinosaurs approach_.

Comment: OP's code is wrong, but your code even if it provided a workaround can't be a good. JSPs are servlets compiled by web server used to write HTML to the out. Leaving HTML in the controller you end up with XSS vulnerability.